# Insert a value of a key in other value

Tags: javascript

I have a list:

```
var lt = {
  "part1" : "p1",
  "part2" : "p2",
  . (another key/value)
  . (another key/value)
  . (another key/value)
  . (another key/value)
}
```

and a variable

```
var myVar = "part2";
```

I want if myVar equal to the lt I want the variable z take the value p2 of lt. I have this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lt.length; i++) {
    if (myVar === lt[i]) {
      z = lt.[i]
    }
}
```

However when I test it chrome console the var lt return undifined

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/55fmggL9/](http://jsfiddle.net/55fmggL9/) this is how you should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dict is not an array. `lt.length` would returns `undefined`.

First test if `lt[myVar]` exists and then copy the value into `z`:

```
var lt = {
   "part1" : "p1",
   "part2" : "p2",
   "part3" : "p3"
}

var myVar = "part2";
var z;

if(typeof lt[myVar] !== "undefined"){
   z = lt[myVar];
}

console.log(z)
---> "p2"
```

or simply:

```
if(myVar in lt){
  z = lt[myVar];
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/55fmggL9/4/

Comment: You can check variable directly without loop: `lt[myVar] == undefined` or `if('part2' in lt)`

Comment: @Max Lipsky I tought myVar was a value, not a key, I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i in lt) {
    if (myVar === i) {
      z = lt[i]
    }
}
```